How to decide the number of partitions when setting up Temporal cluster?
In non-RDBMS, where increasing the number of partitions can speed up writes and reads by parallelism, what is the downside of having too many partitions?
Lets say in Cassandra, the partition key for every row is unique. Whats the downside of this?
On the other hand, what if you have decided on a very few number on fixed number of partitions.
For example, in Temporal (which uses Cassandra), you need to specify a fixed number of partitions while setting up the Temporal cluster. If you have too few partitions, your read/write performance is low at higher loads. But if you increase the number of partitions to a very high number, the resource consumption increases. Why does the resource consumption increase with more number of partitions? ( in a general sense, not limited to Temporal )
Edit: Relation to memtable flushing.
Will more number of partitions cause frequent flushing of the memtable into SSTable, and hence trigger far more compaction and increase the resource usage? If yes, why is number of partitions linked to frequency of memtable flushing?

Now let's preface this by saying that partitions have many different definitions and there is where it can easily be confusing. Especially if Temporal uses partitions to partition Cassandra partitions. But let us assume we mean partitions as in Cassandra partitions. Everything is partitioned by the primary key, and the other columns form rows under each partition.
Cassandra is designed to scale well with the number of partitions but not as well with the size of rows. That is if you have a low number of partition and add rows upon each partition, you are eventually going to run into issues.
The most common issue here is that Cassandra reads an entire partition into memory when it is read, therefore the larger the partition, the more GC pressure you get and the longer the latency on that read.
Flushing has only a direct relation to number of writes. Whether you have less or more partitions shouldn't really matter in this case.
However, all of this gets a lot more complicated when deletes/tombstones are involved but that's a whole other can of worms.
I am not all too familiar with Temporal's usage of Cassandra, but my guess is that it uses 'buckets', bucketing one 'workflow or queue' over multiple Cassandra partitions as a way to keep rows a reasonable size.
If your partitions are too large, then read performance will be impacted because it will require a large read to seek within the partition. On the other side of the spectrum, if you split your 'workflow or queue' into too many partitions, you will need to read all of the different partitions to fetch your queue, thereby impacting resources of the server.

Temporal probably uses Synthetic Sharding on top of Cassandra's shards https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2016/03/15/synthetic-sharding-with-cassandra-or-how-to-deal-with-large-partitions/. During Temporal cluster setup, it asks for a fixed number = number of temporal shards, and ive noticed every row have a PK = shardId . A workflow is guaranteed to be within a given cassandra partition IMO, given that its hash(workflowID)%NumTotalShards = shardID (PK) remains the same
Could you elaborate on why too many shards require a large read to seek within the partition?

In Temporal's case, the issue seems more related to parallelism and less related to large reads. Since Temporal has high consistency requirements, it serializes all requests per shard and uses locking to ensure only one node processes these shards. This means that shards become a unit of parallelism. The more shards you have, the more runs in parallel. Low number of shards means your throughput will be bound by your database latency, but too many shards and you will have resource contention between threads.

Spot on. Those are the exact things I found on Temporal docs - "Shards is the unit of parallelism". But couldn't really answer why. Could you share some resources on this pattern of cassandra usage?
Specifically : why limit parallelism to number of shards? Lets assume N workflows in a given shard have absolutely no relationship to each other, other than the fact that their workflowIDs hashed to the same shardID. What would be the benefit of serializing writes to the single shard when you could instead parallelize WITHIN the shard?(one thread per workflow)

Too many shards and you will have resource contention between threads.   Threads on the DB or threads on the client(here, Temporal server) ? And by contention you mean context switching overhead?

I just realized cassandra is leaderless and "Single Leader Per Shard" model doesn't apply here. Then how does this give more consistency within the shard? AFAIK, singler leader helps order the writes before applying them on the node and replicating the writes on followers

In Temporal, all requests for a shard are executed sequentially, thereby guaranteeing consistency for that shard. The data is sorted by shards, making sure that only one client operates on the partition.

It sounds like you've conflated two different concepts from Temporal and Cassandra.
In Temporal, the History service which persists workflow execution states splits the load into "history shards" or "partitions" which can be run concurrently for scalability. Think of these partitions as database write queues where each queue can process a number of requests to persist the state of Temporal workflow executions.
The number of history shards (numHistoryShards) cannot be changed once the service is running because each shard has a corresponding hashed integer used for queue assignments. Temporal uses an algorithm which hashes each workflow execution's metadata to assign it to a history shard. If the number of shards is changed, the hashed values will also change so the previously assigned hashes will become invalid.
Temporal can have any number of history shards but each shard uses memory and additional computational overhead so the more shards you configure, the more resources will be used by the service so you'll need to do a significant amount of testing to determine the number suitable for your use case. Between 128 and 512 are good starting points. If you're looking for guidance, Mikhail Shilkov has an excellent blog post on Choosing the Number of Shards in Temporal History Service.
It is important to note that the history service partitions (shards) are a completely separate concept from Cassandra partitions. You can have as many partitions as you want in Cassandra.
Also, the number of Cassandra partitions in the cluster don't have anything to do with flushing memtables to disk. The amount of memtable flushing is directly proportional to the volume of database writes. If your cluster is writing lots of data constantly then the memtable will fill up regularly triggering the flushes but if there are no writes taking place then there won't be any flushes either. Cheers!

Keeping temporal aside, at the cassandra-like DB level, is there any downside to having too many partitions ?

And with Temporal, do you have any pointers on why an application like Temporal would want to implement partitioning on top of partitioning offered by the underlying DB ? Choosing the workflowID as partition key would ensure all writes to the given workflow would be serialized within the (DB's) partition right?

No to this -- "Keeping temporal aside, at the cassandra-like DB level, is there any downside to having too many partitions ?" Cassandra is designed to handle massive amounts of data, virtually limitless number of partitions.

"... why an application like Temporal would want to implement partitioning on top of partitioning ..." Like I said, one has nothing to do with the other. It's not partitioning of partitions -- one is a queue for processing events, the other is used for distributing data across hundreds or thousands of nodes in a cluster. Cheers!
